# Connecting to a remote Phymyadmin Mysql server from a local php server

Tags: php

I'm hosting a php server on localhost using command line on Windows, and I'm trying to establish a connection between it and a Mysql database hosted on my school's servers.

I try to make the connection like so:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'db_name');
```

which results in this error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

What might be the cause of this error?

Comment: Is the database accessible from outside the school's network?  Generally that isn't the case by default.  Systems are internal, firewalls block access to things, etc.  You need to work with the school to expose the service to the internet.

Comment: Most likely, this database server is not reachable from the public internet...

Comment: I am on my school's wireless network right now.

Comment: @jaaj: Which may or may not be in the same network segment as the server, or which may have a different firewall, etc.  Either way, you're going to need to know more about the configuration and topology of the school's network.  Check IP addresses, check how you're connecting, try to ping addresses, try to telnet to known open ports, etc.  There are many things that could be blocking the connection.